# Loading PlayN sound assets in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, playn

I followed the [iOS build Wiki](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/iOSBuild), but I can't get the sound assets to load right.

I created the symlink as described:

```
cd mygame/ios 
ln -s ../assets/src/main/resources/assets assets
```

The images in `assets/images` are loaded correctly but not the sound files under `assets/sounds`.

I get the error `WARN: Missing sound: sounds/jump1`

- I see my sound files in Xamarian under 'Solution'
- I have both '.caf' and '.wav' files types
- both files can be opened by 'QuickTime'.
- The same source works on java platform.
- Tested on the iPhone simulator and the real device.

---

Edit:

I checked the iPhone's file system, and noticed that the sound files are never loaded in the device, even when put in the same folder as the `png` files, which explains the FileNotFoundExceptions..

Answer (score 1):

Well I simply had to *include* the sound files as resource as they're not included by default.

In the 'Solution' view, select the sound file(s), right click and `Build Action` and select `BundleResource`.

That did the trick for me.